# dc.js geochoropleth map scaling

Tags: d3.js, svg, scaling, dc.js, choropleth

I have a geo map. Everything is running just fine but the the map that is drawn is incredibly tiny. I have checked the GEOJSON for errors and it works fine. In the JS Box there is a proper working Demo that is commented out to see a working example.

How Do I get my map to Scale up to fill my svg?

http://codepen.io/MichaelArledge/pen/VeeVmY?editors=011

```
$.getJSON("https://googledrive.com/host/0B9jw0MX1C_D_N1plZFhjTlZwY3c", function(json){
    var max = community_per_capita_totals.top(1)[0].value;
    // create a first guess for the projection
    var center = d3.geo.centroid(json)
    var scale  = 100;
    var offset = [width/2, height/2];
    var projection = d3.geo.mercator().scale(scale).center(center).translate(offset);

    // create the path
    var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

    // using the path determine the bounds of the current map and use 
    // these to determine better values for the scale and translation
    var bounds  = path.bounds(json);
    var hscale  = scale*width  / (bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0]);
    var vscale  = scale*height / (bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1]);
    var scale   = (hscale < vscale) ? hscale : vscale;
    var offset  = [width - (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0])/2, height - (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1])/2];

    // new projection
    projection = d3.geo.mercator().center(center).scale(scale).translate(offset);
    path = path.projection(projection);

    chart.dimension(community_dim)
        .group(community_per_capita_totals)
        .width(width)
        .height(height)
        .colors(["#E2F2FF", "#C4E4FF", "#9ED2FF", "#81C5FF", "#6BBAFF", "#51AEFF", "#36A2FF", "#1E96FF", "#0089FF", "#0061B5"])
        .colorDomain([0, max])
        .projection(d3.geo.mercator()
        .center(center)
        .scale(scale)
        .translate(offset))
        .overlayGeoJson(json["features"], "Community")

    dc.renderAll();
  });
```

Comment: I'm not seeing anything, big or small, whether or not I uncomment the part that says to uncomment for a working example. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with your logic for determining the projection.scale(). I am not sure how to modify your logic to give you a custom scale for your map, but here is an example of scale logic I have used in maps before. The factors I am multiplying width and height by are based on the overall aspect ratio of the albersUsa projection, so you would need to tweak those to get a good fit for the mercator projection.

```
var scale = Math.min(width * 1.2, height * 2.1);

var projection = albersUsaPr()
      .scale(scale)
      .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
```

Comment: This worked well. Thank you much. It is good enough to be an answer. Main issue was the drawn map was so damn small that without calculating proper offsets on a scale up would push the map out of the canvas. Thank you Anthony. Will post official link once I clean up the code.

Comment: I got the map to center at 100 scale. Scaling up moves the map to the bottom left corner. I have to start hard coding some offset values. The problem isn't "solved" but my problem was using the .center() method. I was unaware it was a coordinate based system. Once I treated that as a lat lng it became easier to center the map and scale up.


http://codepen.io/MichaelArledge/pen/rxxROr?editors=001

Just having trouble coloring the map now.